# ASP.NET MVC Subcontrollers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i create a sub-controller in ASP.NET MVC?
i.e:

In controller's directory i have a controller named **Users**.Fine.//GET:/Users/Index

Inside controlles folder i have a subfolder named **Groups**,inside that subfolder i have a directory name **Account**,and inside **Account** i have a controller named **Group**.

So,the URL should be:
GET:/Groups/Account/Index

Correct?
But it doenst work,cant find that URL.
It expects:GET:Groups/Index

Any ideias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have subfolders in a controller. You should have a Controller for `Users` and a controller for `Groups`.

In the `Users` controller you will have a `action` called index which will give you the `/Users/Index` view.

In the `Groups` controller you will have an `action` called index and an action called `Account` You then can access these via `/Groups/Index` and /Groups/Account`.

If you wanted to have more nesting then you can use `Areas`. An `Area` will allow you to have a full set of controllers for a "sub folder". For example you can create a `area` called Group. Then you will have a default "Home" controller and view which would act as the index and you could add new controllers and views for each "sub-subpage" i.e `/Groups/Account` where group is the area and account is a controller in that area.